Wordpress live chat requests to a whatsapp group , is this possible?
I have built an online agency i need a chat bot or a contact button in order to make customers able to contact the website and ask for a product or service.
I was thinking on how to automatically send the requests into a whatsapp group i create.
Is there anyway to ask for example (email, phone, and request subject) on the website and send the form in a whatsapp group ?

looks like you can do that whit this api : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/messages
